# Runtime error: signed integer overflow: 3 * 965628297 cannot be represented in type 'int'

Tags: c++

I am solving a problem of code forces. Here is the problem link -> [Problem Link](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1426/F)
My code passes 9 test cases out of 10 and the 10th case is this

> 100

> ??b?a?a???aca?c?a?ca??????ac?b???aabb?c?ac??cbca???a?b????baa?ca??b???cbc??c??ab?ac???c?bcbb?c??abac

and the error I got is this

> wrong answer expected '331264319', found '-2013109745'

> Diagnostics detected issues [cpp.clang++-diagnose]: p71.cpp:14:20: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 3 * 965628297 cannot be represented in type 'int'
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior p71.cpp:14:20 in

Other test cases

> 6 ac?b?c output - 24

> 7 ??????? output - 2835

> 9 cccbbbaaa output - 0

> 100 accbaccabccbbbbabacabaaccacbcbcababbbcbcbcccabcbbc?caaabcabcaaccbccabaaaaccacabbaabcbbccbbababaac output - 14634

This all test cases gives the right answer except the 1st on

and my code which I was submitted is this

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n; cin>>n;  
    string s; cin>>s;
    
    int e=1, a=0, ab=0, abc=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(s[i] == 'a') a+=e;
        else if(s[i]=='b') ab+=a;
        else if(s[i]=='c') abc+=ab;
        else if(s[i]=='?') {
            abc = 3*abc+ab;
            ab = 3*ab+a;
            a = 3*a+e;
            e = 3*e;
        }
    }  
    cout<<abc<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried these things -> Change `int` to `long long int`.

Here the output changes but is still wrong and negative. Output -> `-1959750440526388721`.

Then I tried using unsigned while declaring variables. This also gives me wrong and but not negative. Output -> `2281857551`.

Comment: Obligatory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: Could you [edit] show us some simple test cases.

Comment: Do you see the part in the problem statement where it says `Since the answer can be very large, print it modulo $$$10^{9} + 7$$$.`? You should make sure your program does this. In order to avoid the overflow issues, you should use the modulo logic every time the number might get above that value.

Comment: With your test case the value of `abc` exceeds the capacity even of `long long int`. Add `cout << abc << "\n";` at the end of the for loop and you'll see.

Comment: This kind of exercise expects you to be familiar with the modulus identity `(a * b) % m == ((a % m) * (b % m)) % m`. (And, of course, to read all of it.)

Comment: Thanks, Passerby for the information. I understand!

Comment: I don't know about modulo logic, please explain a little bit more... Karl Knechtel and molbdnilo

Comment: I did not know this, jabberwocky. Well I tried this too but still not getting expected output

Comment: I got `5250892003678722536788615695`, before modulo `1'000'000'007`.  After the modulo, `331264319`.  Huzzah!  Codeforces is a programming contest, to challenge yourself to solve the problem.  It has its own forums.  Coming SO for help is like waiting a day to do crossword puzzles so you can use the answer key.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. Can you please tell me, what should I write in my code... As I am a beginner, I have no idea how to use the % operator to avoid these issues.  @Eljay

Comment: That's a big ask for a Q&A forum like this.  What you really need is a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need the result "modulo 10^9+7", you can reduce the result of all additions and multiplications "modulo 10^9+7" (i.e. find the remainder after division by 10^9+7 - this is what the `%` operator does).

In the code, you can either do this in each calculation or at the end of the loop. Applying the first option (and a few good habits) looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Avoid using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned n; std::cin >> n;  
    std::string s; std::cin >> s;
    
    unsigned e = 1, a = 0, ab = 0, abc = 0;  // We do not need negative numbers
    unsigned m = 1000000007;   // Calculate result modulo 10^9+7
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(s[i] == 'a') a = (a + e) % m;
        else if(s[i]=='b') ab = (ab + a) % m;
        else if(s[i]=='c') abc = (abc + ab) % m;
        else if(s[i]=='?') {
            abc = (3 * abc + ab) % m;
            ab = (3 * ab + a) % m;
            a = (3 * a + e) % m;
            e = (3 * e) % m;
        }
    }  
    std::cout << abc << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and code. I like your answer and I understand it too...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, not every integer is created equal. They have a max size in memory.

The issue is that there's not enough memory to represent such a large number, so the computer doesn't have enough space to represent your number.

EDIT:
A better solution would be to use the % operator to avoid these issues. According to the exercise, that's what's recommended

Old solution:

A solution would be to use a different type of int like a int64_t (or if exact width isn't needed then long long would work too)

Comment: Even `int64_t` is not big enough for his use case.

Comment: Yeah, I'll edit it

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. Can you please tell me, what should I write in my code... As I am a beginner, I have no idea how to use the % operator to avoid these issues.

Comment: I'm not sure about this particular situation, but I think codeforces should give you some hints in the problem itself

Comment: All you really need to know is that % gives the remainder after dividing 2 numbers. So 5 % 2 will give 1

Comment: @Tapesh: If you are such a beginner ("I have no idea how to use the % operator") then the entire solution wouldn't be very helpful to you either. And I doubt that it's your solution too.